# Auto select drop down based on value from viewmodel

Tags: jquery, html, knockout.js

how to auto select an option in the drop down based on the another property from view model. drop down has it's own array as source. how do I do that using knockout(3.0) or Jquery.

```
<tbody id"formOne" data-bind="foreach:{ data: viewModel.EmployeeDetails}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" data-bind="value: Name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="ddGender"
                    data-bind="options: viewModel.Genders,
                               optionsText: 'GenderText',
                               optionsValue: 'GenderId',
                               optionsCaption : 'Select..'"></select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
<script>
    var Employee = function (Name, id) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.GenderId = id;
    };
    var Gender = function (GenderName, id) {
        this.GenderText = GenderName;
        this.GenderId = id;
    }
    function EmployeeViewModel() {
        EmployeeDetails: ko.observableArray([
            new Employee("A", 1),
            new Employee("B", 2),
            new Employee("C", 1)
        ])
        Genders: ko.observableArray([
            new Gender("F", 1),
            new Gender("M", 2)
        ])
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(new EmployeeViewModel());
    })
</script>
```

there will be a row for each employee and each row will have a drop down for Gender and that Gender drop down should be auto selected based on GenderId from employee.

Answer (score 0):

can be done by Adding  "value: GenderId"  to drop down data-bind.